# In MySQL how can I set a limit to an attribute

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I created my ER and all my tables in MySQL but I need to know how to set a max number allowed for one of my attributes.

The attribute is a vehicle and I want my database to set a limit to 10 and not allow the user to add an 11th car.

I'm not too familiar with triggers. How can I start?

Comment: Are you talking about 10 rows with the same 'car'?

Comment: If you'd be so kind to show the tables structure it would help providing a solution. Without it, there are just way too many posibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just count the number of rows in your table before inserting?
If the count return 10, don't insert.

Comment: thank you, I did not know that we could count the rows but I will look into that....very new at this but below are my tables:

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't provide a mechanims to prevent a INSERT INTO a table with triggers. 
A solution is use a trigger with a not null column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER carsCheck BEFORE INSERT ON cars
for each row
begin
  DECLARE counter INT;
  SET counter = (select count(id) from cars);
  if counter > 10 then
    NEW.notNulCol = null;
  end if;
end;
```